# The number of intersection points of the graphs of $f(x)=x^2+5x+7$ and $g(x)=x+3$?

Tags: functions

What is the number of intersection points of the graphs of $f(x)=x^2+5x+7$ and $g(x)=x+3$?

I solved the equation $$x^2+5x+7=x+3\\x^2+4x+4=0\\(x+2)^2=0\\x=-2$$
What does $x=-2$ mean? I am not sure even if I am supposed to solve the equation. How can we think about it? Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: $x=-2$ is point where both functions take the same value, as the graph shows.  $f(-2)=g(-2)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of roots of $f(x) = g(x)$ are precisely the number of intersection points of the two curves, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. In your case, there is a repeated root, namely $x = -2$. So, there  is only one distinct point of intersection.

To better understand why we solve $f(x) = g(x)$ to get the intersection points - ask yourself, what is an intersection point? It is a point that lies on both the curves $f$ and $g$, so it better take the same value on both the curves (or you should see a very visual contradiction).

Comment: Thank you for the response! I don't understand completely why we're solving the equation $f(x)=g(x)$ to get the intersection points. An intersection point is a point that lies on both the curves $f$ and $g$. Everything is clear so far. But why should it take the same value on both the curves?

Comment: Suppose the intersection point is $(x,y)$. It lies on $f$, and so $y = f(x)$. It also lies on $g$, so we have $y = g(x)$ too. Clearly, $f(x) = g(x)$. Does that make it clearer? @Medi

Comment: A little more, I think. May I ask you to clarify it a little more? Thank you!

Comment: Sure! Do you have any specific questions? If not, I'll try to clarify it further from my end. If you do have particular questions, it'd be easier to make clarifications! @Medi

Comment: Yes. Okay, we're supposing that the intersection point of the curves $f$ and $g$ is $A(x;y)$. Can you tell me when exactly a point lies on a curve?

Comment: A point $(x,y)$ lies on a curve $f$ if and only if $y = f(x)$. It might be helpful to revisit how curves are drawn and what they are. How do you sketch the curve of a function $f$? For every point $x$ in the domain, you find $f(x)$ and mark the point $(x,f(x))$ on the graph. So, all points on the curve are of this form, i.e. the $y$-coordinate and $x$ coordinate of a point on the curve are related by $y = f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The "$x = -2$" part just represents the $x$-coordinate of the point of intersection between the two graphs. Also, since you only got one $x$-coordinate, this just represents that there is only one intersection point. But for this "$x = -2$" to make sense, you need to plug into one of the original functions to get the $y$-coordinate, where the $y$-coordinate for this intersection point is $f(x)$ or $g(x)$, deciding on whatever function you want to plug the $x$-coordinate back into. In this case, let's say you plug it back into the function $g(x) = x + 3$. Substitute $x = -2$ back into this equation. $g(x) = 1$. So, the $y$-coordinate is $1$ for this intersection point. So the intersection point that you would be visualizing would be the point $(-2, 1)$.